# Help with usb Joystick

Tags: manjaro, joystick

My joystick does not send any input to my computer regardless it being recognized by the system. As a additional information it begins to send input if i boot windows then reboot to Manjaro. Someone has any idea how to resolve this or even what is being sent to the joystick to make him work?
I don't know if here is the right place to ask that, if it isnt i'm sorry.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems kind of broad.  Could you clarify what you mean by "Does not send any input" and "recognized by the system"?  Are you actually using some sort of tool to monitor electrical signals across the usb cable from the joystick?

Comment: The joystick appears as /dev/input/js0, recognized as a Xbox 360 pad, but when i run jstest /dev/input/js0 and try any button it doesnt appear to send/recognize nothing. It appears that it only works when i boot windows with it plugged then reboot to manjaro.